# Form submit by jQuery gives 'null' data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to submit a form using jQuery, everything seems to work except the part it returns 'null' on everything.

My jQuery/Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#loginForm').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var $form = $(this);

            var $url = $form.attr('action');
            var $username = $form.find("input[name=username]");
            var $password = $form.find("input[name=password]");

            if($username.val().length > 0 && $password.val().length > 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: $url,
                    data: {
                        'username': $username.val(),
                        'password': $password.val()
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        alertify.success("Username: " + data.username + "\n Password: " + data.password);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alertify.error("Username and/or password is not provided!");
            }
        })
    })
```

The result:
[image: The result]

Comment: can you show the console logs and network entries

Comment: To add to @HimanshuTanwar request - could you also post your html and explain what do you mean by `returns null` - where exactly does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using JQuery, have a look at `.serializeArray()`. This can be used to get the forms data. Remember only input values which have a `name` HTML attribute will be serialized.

check out the docs [here](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

**resulting js**

```
var $form = $(this);
var formDataArray = $form.serializeArray();
```

Make sure that your button has `type="submit"` HTML attribute also.

I hope this helps,

Rhys

Answer (score 0):

In answer on the request of @HitmanshuTanwar and @Eihwaz,

**This is my (related) HTML code:**

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form" id="loginForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign In</button>
            </form>
```

**My (related) PHP code:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2016, Experminator (Ronald).
 */

    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        echo($username);
        echo($password);
    }

    die("Invalid.");
?>
```

**My (related) javascript/jquery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#loginForm').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var $form = $(this);

            var $username = $form.find('input[name=username]');
            var $password = $form.find('input[name=password]');

            if($username.val().length > 0 && $password.val().length > 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'login.php',
                    data: { username: $username.val(), password: $password.val() },
                    success: function(data) {
                        alertify.success("Username: " + data.username + " <> Password: " + data.password);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alertify.error("Username and/or password is not provided!");
            }
        })
    })
```

**The result of the 'Console':** 
[image: Console]

**And the result of the 'Networking':**
[image: Networking]